# How to Change Buttons Color In Magento2

Tags: magento2, theme

How to change `Buttons` color in `Magento2`?

Answer (score 5):

I was strugglying with this too, here is what I would suggest.

Add this to your new theme `_extend.less` file

```
@button-primary__background: <your color here >;
```

e.g

```
@button-primary__background: #ccc;
```

You will likely want to change the border colour to, which can be done like so :

```
@button-primary__border: #ccc;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Ben, any help same issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328933/57334 thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Override the values in your theme file, which name as _theme.less, change value as below:

```
@button__color: red;
@button__background: yellow;
```

run this command `php bin/magento cache:clean`
refresh your page

Answer (score -3):

In Magento 2 you can edit buttons property from below path:

```
magento_installed_directory\lib\web\css\source\lib\variables\_buttons.less
```

flush your cache

Comment: Is it then the intension for global style overrides that we edit the content of that dir?

Comment: yes, you are right, we need to copy those file in our theme package, and then edit

Comment: I find this answer useful. While you can't edit files in vendor directly you can just create a file in your theme `web/css/source/_theme.less` and just override the variables there. Just use the mentioned file as a reference, or a list of defined variables, if you will.